# Как в элемент массива byte[] записать такой байт - B94?

Tags: c#

Как в элемент массива byte[] записать такой байт - B94 ?

Выдаёт ошибку значение константы 2964 не может быть преобразовано в byte.

```
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
    int ReadBytes(int baseAddress, byte[] offsets)
                {
                    string qwe;
                    int ewq;
                    if (pID != 0 && baseAddress != 0 && offsets.Length != 0)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                        var bytesread = new IntPtr();
                        var handle = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false, pID);
                        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (IntPtr)baseAddress, buffer, 4, out bytesread);
                        for(int i = 0; i < offsets.Length; i++)
                        {
                            baseAddress = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
                            baseAddress += offsets[i];
                            ReadProcessMemory(handle, (IntPtr)baseAddress, buffer, 4, out bytesread);
                            qwe = "0x" + Convert.ToString(baseAddress, 16);
                            ewq = Convert.ToInt32(qwe, 16);
                            if (i == 3)
                            {
                                return ewq;
                            }
                        }
                        var result = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer ,0);
                        CloseHandle(handle);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(baseAddress.ToString());
                    return 0;
                }

var staticBall_adress = 0x025DFDA8; //Начальный адрес
var offsets_2 = new short[] { 0xB94, 0x04 }; //вот эти смещения (b94 не влазит)
int rb_2 = ReadBytes(staticBall_adress, offsets_2); //Конечный адрес
```

Comment: `byte` - диапазон значений: 0..255. Oткуда у Вас берется такой байт `B94`?

Comment: Читаю указатели, и B94 это одно смещение

Comment: В байт не влезет, расширяйте до short. Также, гипотетически вам нужно записать 94 и 0B (или 0B, а потом 94) если вы этот массив байт планируете записывать на диск.

Comment: @qweqwe тогда почему Вы решили, что это должен быть  `byte`?

Comment: Смещение?? Так смещение (допустим, в файле) может быть и за пределами int, если файл большой. Посмотрите, например, в файловых операциях и стримах потому long и используется.

Comment: Решил что должен быть byte[] потому что использую этот массив в функции нахождения адреса, сейчас её залью

Comment: @qweqwe э-э-э, и что, это единcтвенная ошибка компилятора?

Comment: Да, только это и пишет

Comment: Да? А например pID откуда берётся?

Comment: Береться из Id процесса, которого берем handle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. В c# тип byte [предполагает](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5bdb6693(v=vs.120).aspx) диапазон от 0 до 255.

В файловых операциях или стримах в C# обычно используются long, см. например какой-нибудь [FileStream.Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream.position(v=vs.110).aspx).

Вероятно, Вам в вашей задаче также нужно использовать long. Либо если вы читаете файл и уверены, что его размер достаточно невелик -- используйте int.

Updated. Для использования в ReadProcessMemory вам должно хватить и int и int64. Смотрел описания [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34467311/5752652).

Update2. Нахождение адреса по смещению и базовому адресу тривиально, не понимаю в чём проблема?

```
long baseAddr = 0x025DFDA8; // Начальный адрес
long offset = 0xB94; // Смещение
long addr = baseAddr + offset; // 25E093C
```

Или два смещения от базового адреса:

```
long baseAddr = 0x025DFDA8; // Начальный адрес
long[] offsets = new long[] { 0xB94, 0x04  }; // Смещения
long addr = baseAddr + offsets[0] + offsets[1]; // 25E0940
```

Comment: Не получается, поставлю вопрос по другому, как мне найти значение адреса на который указывает другой адрес со смещением +B94 +68, если мне известен другой адрес?

Comment: @qweqwe Просто суммой: базовый адрес плюс смещение. (См. пример, дополнил в вопрос). У вас два смещения? Или базовый адрес плюс смещение относительно базового и ещё раз смещение?

Comment: 2 смещения. 006C0584 [+B94 +68], простое добавление не подходит, потому-что эти адреса беруться из ReadProcessMemory, то-есть из одного процесса, а если добавлять и не учитывать процесс, выходит совсем не тот адресс

Comment: Странно. А мне уже казалось, что вы хотите прочитать 0x04 байт начиная с 0x025DFDA8 + 0xB94

Comment: @qweqwe А вы не пробовали на листочке нарисовать смещения, мне кажется было бы наглядно видно, что вам именно нужно. В качестве гипотезы: 0x001F0FFF + 0xB94 - ( 0x025DFDA8 + 0x04). Либо сами разберётесь какая нужна формула, либо сможете прикрепить скан/фото к вопросу. Пока не понятна задача.

Comment: @qweqwe: В любом случае, если на ваш первоначальный вопрос дан исчерпывающий ответ, ставьте галку.

Comment: Спасибо всем, проблема решена. Я сделал другую функцию, ReadBytes там всё аналогично, только вместо byte[] поставил short, когда я в прошлой функции заменил byte на short у меня не компилилось, и я сказал что не работает, а сейчас всё нормально, спасибо всем, расходимся.